# Google Analytics: iOS App executed under Linux

Tags: ios, linux, google-analytics

I am developing an iOS app. It has Google Analytics (GA) built in, which is used after the user agrees.
A few days ago, GA claimed that my app has been executed under Linux i686 (**not** under any iOS version) using a cell phone provider in Samara, Russia.

My question is: Is this possible at all?

If not, this must be a GA error.
If possible, someone could have hacked my repository. How could I check this?

**EDIT:**

I know that my question sounds silly. But some time before I got this info from GA, I realized from the logs that somebody from Samara tried a brute force attack to the screensharing port of the Mac hosting the OS X server that hosts my repository. I thought I had secured the VNC connection well enough, but maybe I was not right...

Comment: Could the person who downvoted my question please tell me why?

Comment: How many hits are you getting, from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, my previous answer was wrong.

By now I learned from [a discussion on a Google Analytics forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/2saSsbmPbSg) that many iOS developers have this problem. Apparently a Russian bot under Linux is systematically testing GA tracking numbers.

Such an access does not provide any other app data (since the app is not generation them), and these accesses can be filtered out in GA easily.

I have no idea what benefit the spammer gains by this, though...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to my 1st question is:
My iOS app did run on the Xcode simulator, and Xcode was executed under OS X on a virtual machine running under Linux.
Sorry, I did not think about this possibility before.